# jQuery Error: Var is defined but says that its not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my source

```
var linkData = Array();

$.each(links, function(index){
    var obj =   { 
                    link: links[index].href,
                    name: links[index].innerHTML
                };

    linkdata.push(obj);
});
console.log(linkData);
```

this is the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: linkdata is not defined
```

but its declaired....

what am i doing wrong ?!?!?

i tried to declaire it like

```
var linkData = Array();
linkData = Array();
var linkData = [];
linkData = [];
```

no changes...

Comment: Correct typo error `linkdata` to `linkData`

Comment: oh my god, you right ^^ guess i have to make a pause... programming to long hahaha big THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
linkdata.push(obj);
```

to

```
linkData.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's Key sensitive is `linkData` instead of `linkdata`.

```
var linkData = Array();

$.each(links, function(index){
    var obj =   { 
                    link: links[index].href,
                    name: links[index].innerHTML
                };

    linkData.push(obj); //you had linkdata
});
console.log(linkData);
```

Answer (score 2):

`linkData` not `linkdata`, correct that